# Excel VB.Net - Convert array to range and set value to worksheet

Tags: excel, vb.net, excel-dna

I have been trying to find a solution for this error for a few hours, all the solutions I found didn't fix the error I get when setting Range.Value2 = Value
while trying to populate an array into an excel spreadsheet.
Currently the array has a length of only 1 in size, I've tried it with bigger array and so far it just throws me this exception in the last line of code:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC'
```

The code:

```
Imports ExcelDna.Integration
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Public Function TestFunction()

    'Dim data = New Object(1, 2) {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}}
    Dim app As Excel.Application = CType(ExcelDnaUtil.Application, Excel.Application)
    Dim worksheet As Excel.Worksheet = CType(app.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet, Excel.Worksheet)
    Dim rng As Excel.Range = CType(worksheet.Cells(2, 1), Excel.Range)

    Dim arr() As String = New String() {"hello world"}

    'Tried this rng.Value2 = arr as well
    rng.Resize(1, arr.Length).Value2 = arr
End Function
```

My goal is to be able to copy a matrix to the excel spreadsheet but so far I
just need help in fixing the error that the code throws with an array.
Thank you for future replies!

Comment: Normally Excel does not allow you to set sheet values inside a UDF. Just return the array from the function, and call as an array function from the sheet (select the right size region for the function, then Ctrl+Shift+Enter to set the formula as an array formula).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Range.Value2` is a two-dimensional array/matrix, you have to use such an array, too.

```
Dim arrLine1() As String = {"Hello World!", "red", "green"}

' convert to 2-dimensional array
Dim arr(,) As String
Redim arr(1, arrLine1.Length)
For i = 0 To arrline1.Length - 1
    arr(0, i) = arrLine1(i)
Next

rng.Resize(1, arr.GetUpperBound(1)).Value2 = arr
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have tried the following code and I keep getting the same error as I have mentioned above.

Comment: Let me start by saying KekuSemau is correct, and you will need to change your code to write a rectangular 2d array to a RANGE of cells instead of a 1d array to a single cell. That said, the error code you're getting is not related to writing an array to a single cell, that would throw a SafeArrayTypeMismatchException...if you don't use the method shown in this answer, you will get that exception once you fix your initial error. There are several people who have found different solutions to that error on SO, google "Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC" and try some of them out

Comment: Alright, thank you very much for the reply. I will look for more solutions!